# YouTube Data API: how to change schedule to publish video?

Tags: php, video, youtube-data-api

YouTube Data API (PHP): I tried to change schedule to publish video but not working. how to change?

`$playlistItem` is object of `Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItem`:

```
//$playlistItem:Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItem
$contentDetails=$playlistItem->getContentDetails(); 

//not working
$contentDetails->setStartAt("2018-12-24T05:42:08.000Z");
```

no error message. I checked the value $contentDetails->getStartAt(), It has been changed on same script after setStartAt(), but not changed on dashboard on youtube studio and different script without setStartAt().

Comment: $playlistItem is object of Google_Service_YouTube_PlaylistItem

Comment: I've added your comment to your post. Please [edit] your post and add _how_ your code is not working and what it does instead, and also what error you get back.